# sftpd allows file creation, but not overwriting existing files on HP-UX

Tags: sftp, hp-ux

one of our operational systems (linux) pushes files to our server (HPUX) using SFTP.

Sometimes (..) they need to resend an updated version using the same file_name, but the sftp server doesn't allow them to overwrite.

the unix login used for copying has read/write/execute permissions on the target directory, so I assume I need to modify the SFTPD config?

can you point me towards documentation or howto's

Answer (score 1):

What are the permission of the uploaded files?

Having write rights for a directory does not allow you to modify existing files (unless you have right to those files as well). It only enables you to delete them.

SSH daemon on HP-UX supports option `SftpUmask` which specified the rights newly uploaded files get.

Comment: We've since (more than a year ago) replaced the HPUX servers with newer hardware running linux. .. and the problems have disappeared. My guess "someone" tweaked the sftp daemon settings.. thanks for the tip, I hope others will profit!